# xpath - how to use contains to filter the xpath?

Tags: xpath

I got this xpath

```
//td[@id='datepicker-54143-1002-23']/button/span
```

The numbers 54142-1002 will change. 23 is the date. How can I use contains to make the xpath? So I would like to make the xpath contain datepicker and 23 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
//td[starts-with(@id, 'datepicker-') and ends-with(@id, '-23')]/button/span
```

But note that [`ends-with`](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/xpath-ends-with) available from XPath version 2.0

Comment: Thanks JaSON! The start-with works but not the ends-with. Can I use contains instead? How do I know if the webpage support version1 or 2?

Answer (score 2):

If `ends-with` doesn't work for you, as @JaSON suggested in his answer, it's because you're using XPATH 1.0, and `ends-with` is available only in XPATH 2.0.
Try this instead:

`//td[starts-with(@id,'datepicker-') and substring(@id,string-length(@id)-2)='-23']`

Please note that if "23" changes to string of different length you'll have to adjust "-2" part accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanks also jaSON!

Comment: @Ludvig you can accept this answer if it solved your problem